# How heavy is hardware tessellation?

Tags: graphics, shader, directx-11, tessellation

If tessellation gives a bonus over just using high-poly models,then why do modern 2012 games still use gigantic models that take a lot of hard disk space instead of tessellating it all and just adjusting the tessellation factor to depend on distance from camera,creating a nice level of detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get back detail by tessellation that was not there in the first place. It just means those models would be even bigger without it being available.

> In its most basic form, tessellation is a method of breaking down polygons into finer pieces. For example, if you take a square and cut it across its diagonal, you’ve “tessellated” this square into two triangles. By itself, tessellation does little to improve realism. For example, in a game, it doesn’t really matter if a square is rendered as two triangles or two thousand triangles—tessellation only improves realism if the new triangles are put to use in depicting new information.
>
> When a displacement map (left) is applied to a flat surface, the
>   resulting surface (right) expresses the height information encoded in
>   the displacement map. The simplest and most popular way of putting the
>   new triangles to use is a technique called displacement mapping. A
>   displacement map is a texture that stores height information. When
>   applied to a surface, it allows vertices on the surface to be shifted
>   up or down based on the height information. For example, the graphics
>   artist can take a slab of marble and shift the vertices to form a
>   carving. Another popular technique is to apply displacement maps over
>   terrain to carve out craters, canyons, and peaks

http://www.nvidia.com/object/tessellation.html

[image]

Comment: yes,that's what i meant - why don't developers use tessellation+displacement maps instead of pushing gigantic models to the GPU?

Comment: Without those "gigantic models" what would you be applying tessellation to? If you are asking why everybody does not use tessellation for everything when they could then perhaps it's years of investment in a engine that would be expensive to retool. If it ain't broke...

Comment: "Without those "gigantic models" what would you be applying tessellation to" well you can just make a high poly model in 3dsmax and then bake a displacement map from it's details,then use Optimize to reduce it's polycount 10fold,then use the low poly version in your game,tesselate it and apply the displacement map,thus getting dynamic LoD and everything

Comment: depends on your definition of "gigantic" then I suppose! The point is you have all the tools to do that, except the "game" part. People are still (re)using engines from many years ago. Engines cost tons of money to write. Stuff like that changes slow.

Comment: IMHO, the tools for tessellation, and their adoption into the asset creation pipeline hasn't reached maturity.  Give it a little while.  Additionally, ideas and toolkits like [Pixar's OpenSubDiv](https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/OpenSubdiv) will help drive adoption.

Comment: Something someone seemingly hasn't pointed out yet: Displacement maps use memory too. A single 4k 8bpc displacement map for example would take 16.8mb of VRAM. Are you gauging memory consumption using the compressed file size?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why nobody uses hardware tessellation in games is, that ca. 60% of all game player are console player and aslong the console doesnt support shadermodel5, there is no reason to do games that uses hardware tessellation. Even if they do, they may be have to do a game in dx9 and dx11 because it is not really good downward compatible... but maybe there is an other reason to!

With the new consoles comming out this year, maybe HW Tessellation gets an other change ;)